# Obter último valor da ID e somar +1 em Banco de Dados SQL

Tags: sql

Sou novo em nessa linguagem, anteriormente estava usando um `auto_increment` para salvar a ID sequencialmente no banco, porem encontrei problemas em outras funções. A minha dúvida é: Como faço para obter o ultimo "id" do banco e adicionar +1 - Segue o que eu estava tentando, porem sem êxito:

```
<?php 

    include 'conecta_mysql.inc';

    $id1 = 'SELECT LAST(id) FROM t_saida';
    $id = $id1+1;
    $os = $_POST['os'];
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $tech = $_POST['tech'];
    $descri = $_POST['descri'];
    $pag = $_POST['pag'];
    $valor = $_POST['valor'];

 $query = "INSERT INTO t_saida (id,data,os,tech,descri,pag,valor) VALUES ('$id','$data','$os','$tech','$descri','$pag','$valor')"; 


if (mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
      echo "Inserido com sucesso!";
      echo "<script>window.open ('','_self')</script>";
} else {
      echo "Erro: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($link);
}
mysqli_close($link);


?>
```

Reparem que eu insiro os dados através de um formulário, e tento incrementar a **id** com a variável `$id1` e `$id`.

Comment: No lugar de LAST, utilize MAX no SQL, porém você precisa submeter essa query para retornar o valor.

Comment: Submeter, você fala, antes de inserir os dados do formulario?

Comment: Algo como assim:  $id1 = 'SELECT max(id) FROM t_saida';
    mysqli_query($link, $id1); ?

Answer (score 0):

Poderia ser algo como:

```
"INSERT INTO t_saida (id,data,os,tech,descri,pag,valor) VALUES ((select coalesce(max(id),0)+1 from t_saida),'$data','$os','$tech','$descri','$pag','$valor')";
```

Mas o auto incremment é do banco de dados, independe da linguagem.

Comment: É por aí mesmo amigo, porem acarretou esse erro: "You can't specify target table 't_saida' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: isso é em um insert... não em um update...